# Switching between many Highcharts using buttons or link text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I originally wanted to display a lot of highcharts on my website in a side-by-side sort of configuration. Now I have instead been trying to include just one highchart on the site and give the viewers the option to switch between them using buttons. I am a total novice at this so I am having a few problems doing this. I have been trying to use the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-setdata/

-> but theres a few differences between this example and my setup which I am having troubles with.

I populate my highcharts from a database using some JSON template I found online (and since theres so many charts, I keep all that code in a separate data.php file). All works fine.

Heres an example of what I am trying to do - I have inserted two highcharts in the following code, but theres going to be a lot more. Each of the charts have different tooltip and y-axis options etc. so I don't think it will work to just change the data itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('chart1').ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart1',
                type: 'column',
                marginTop: 40,
                marginBottom: 75
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Revenues',
                x: 25 //center
            },

            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                showInLegend: false,
                tickAmount: 11,
                endOnTick: false,
                startOnTick: true,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, '.', ',');
                                }
                },
                title: {
                    text: '<?php echo $unitCurr; ?>'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0,'.',',');
                }
            },
            series: []
        }
        var tableName = '<?php echo $tableName; ?>'
        $.getJSON("../../companies/charts/data.php", {id: escape(tableName)}, function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });       


 $('chart2').ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart2',
                type: 'column',
                marginTop: 40,
                marginBottom: 75
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Net profit or loss',
                x: 25 //center
            },

            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                showInLegend: false,
                tickAmount: 11,
                endOnTick: false,
                startOnTick: true,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, '.', ',');
                                }
                },
                title: {
                    text: '<?php echo $unitCurr; ?>'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1,'.',',');
                }
            },
            series: []
        }
        var tableName = '<?php echo $tableName; ?>'
        $.getJSON("../../companies/charts/data.php", {id: escape(tableName)}, function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[6];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart1"></div>
    <button id="button" class="autocompare">Set new data</button>
</body>


</html>
```

Progress so far:

I have tried to delete the div and creating a new one using the code below. This results in delete of the 'chart1' but does not create the 'chart2'. Also - There is in fact about 10 charts which has to be created so I am wondering if anyone can think of a way in which each of the 10 buttons would always delete the current chart above and instead create the chart dedicated to that specific button?

```
    <script>
    $('#button').on('click',function(){
        var elem = document.getElementById("chart1");
        elem.remove();
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = "chart2";
    });
    </script>
```

I'm also very happy if you could just provide me with links that explains how to do this or how to get a better understanding of the whole thing. I am very sure this has to be done using either javascript or ajax but I have so little experience using these so I just need a little inspiration.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Changing the containing element's id after the chart has been rendered there won't do anything. I wouldn't change the id at any point, as it's not necessary at all. Just destroy the old chart, and draw the new chart when the button is clicked. Or, since the only things that seem to change between charts are the data and the titles, just update the data and the titles on button click.

Comment: Thank you for your message jlbriggs! I have edited the post and added some code where i try to first delete the div and then create another one. That does delete the 'chart1' but does not generate 'chart2' instead. Also - there is in fact about 10 different charts, so I think this is a better solution than changing titles, legends and so on. However, I know that I will need to come up with a solution so that the script always deletes the chart currently showing rather than a specific one. Do you have any ideas for doing this? (not that I want you to create the code for me). Thanks.

Comment: There is no need (or desire) to delete the div, or change its ID - Highcharts has a method to destroy the chart itself, and then you can simply create a new chart, in the existing div, with its existing ID, with the new chart options. If you're going to have a different chart config for each chart, I would either 1) store that chart config as a file that you load along with the data (or store the config in the same file that you get the data from), or 2) create a `chartOptions` object with a node for each chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it something like this - on button click, destroy the chart and build a new one in its place.

This example works on data and chart objects defined on the page, but you could instead, inside of this click event handler, fetch your external data, and your external chart options definition, based  on the same key obtained from the clicked button.

```
  $(document).on('click', '.chart-update', function() {
    chart.destroy(); <-- destroys the current chart object
    $('#container').highcharts(chartOptions[$(this).data('chartName')]); <-- rebuilds a new chart
    chart = $('#container').highcharts(); <-- re-associates the 'chart' variable with the current chart object
  });
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/7ntyzo6u/

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helps me out.

Comment: I have just posted a follow-up question on this subject which I would of course greatly appreciate if you have the time to take a look at! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033411/retrieving-json-data-in-highcharts